# Neo4j: How to return single entities from a path

Tags: neo4j

I am running:

```
MATCH p=(a)-[*2]-() where id(a) = 0 RETURN *
```

against:

```
CREATE 
(P1:Person),
(P2:Person),
(P3:Person),
(P4:Person),
(P5:Person),
(P6:Person),
(P7:Person)

CREATE 
(A1:Address),
(A2:Address),
(A3:Address),
(A4:Address)

CREATE 
(P1)-[:Friend]->(P3),
(P5)-[:Friend]->(P7)

CREATE
(P1)-[:House]->(A1),
(P1)-[:House]->(A2),
(P2)-[:House]->(A2),
(P2)-[:House]->(A4),
(P3)-[:House]->(A3),
(P4)-[:House]->(A2),
(P5)-[:House]->(A1),
(P6)-[:House]->(A3)
```

and it returns the expected values

The problem is when the database has only one value, example:

```
CREATE 
(P1:Person)
```

In that case the search path is empty. How can I generalise the query above to get structures that have less then depth 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search path is empty because the pattern you define in a `MATCH` should be there.

You can :

a) use `OPTIONAL MATCH` for the relationship part :

```
MATCH (a)
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(a)-[*2]-()
RETURN *
```

Which would return a and null for p

b) use a length 0..x for relationship depth :

```
MATCH p=(a)-[*0..2]-() RETURN *
```

Which would return the same as in a) , there are differences though

In your query, paths MUST be of length 2, here paths can be between length 0 and 2

An explanation about relationship depths :

http://graphaware.com/graphaware/2015/05/19/neo4j-cypher-variable-length-relationships-by-example.html